# How to create a personnal account in django?

Tags: django

I was wondering of how to create a personal account in django.

For example I have two users in my project the details of one user-login cannot be seen by another...I mean User1 will have his/her personal data which will be not visible to User2...

Basically,I mean to say how to differentiate datas of Users in django...

Any guess??
Actually I am very much new to django. Thats why facing this difficulty.It will be real help if anyone can suggest me to solve this problem..

Thank you...

Comment: have you followed any tutorial? if yes then post the error.  As explaining whole `user_role` concept would be out of question.

Comment: Work through this, that will answer most basic questions: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: There isn't any errors at all..I was wondering how to diffrentiate user accounts in django...Also if you can suggest me any tutorial it will also be a real help

Comment: You differentiate data of different users by creating a foreign key field that references the user's primary key: User.id

Comment: Do you mean account types? Like roles? That would probably be "groups" in Django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#groups

Comment: I have done that diffrentiating through foreign keys..But if I login with another user the same information is visible to me which I have created for another user..My main problem is I cannot diffrentiate users...

Comment: Thank you @C14L that is what I was looking for...